# push object from an array to observableArray

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

so I'm trying to push the object stored in an array when a checkbox is called with knockout to an observable array.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checked, click: $root.saveSelected"/>
```

JS:

```
var definition = [
      {title: 'some text', checked: ko.observable(false), definition: '<p>Some HTML</p>'}
],

var viewModel = {

selectedItems: ko.observableArray([]),

saveSelected: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < definition.length; ++i) {
        if (viewModel.definition[i].checked().value === true) {
          viewModel.selectedItems.push(definition[i]);
        }
      }
    }
```

So I'm pretty sure that my if statement is what's causing the issue here, but I'm not sure what I did wrong. But the outcome should be that for every checkbox that is selected, that object (now with a value of true for 'checked') should get pushed to the selectedItems array so that (with this example) the blank selectedItems array should have the object

```
{title: 'some text', checked: ko.observable(false), definition: '<p>Some HTML</p>'}
```

in it after the saveSelection function runs.

--EDIT--
The fiddle for this code: http://jsfiddle.net/imagitron/mMc6k/6/

Comment: You don't have a `value` property inside your `checked` observable so you just need to write `if (viewModel.definition[i].checked() === true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ".value" when accessing the checked observable:

```
if (viewModel.definition[i].checked() === true) {
...
```

Knockout manages setting the `value` of the HTML `<input>` control.  All you need to know is that it's an observable with either `true` or `false` value.

Comment: I tried this, and it still isn't populating the selectedItems array, I edited my post to link to a fiddle of the code

Comment: This ended up working, all I had to do in addition to this was replace viewModel.definition[i] with simply definition[i]

Answer (score 0):

First off, `click: $root.saveSelected` doesn't match `saveSelection: function() {`

Second issue

```
for (var i = 0; i < definition.length; ++i) {
    if (viewModel.definition[i].checked() === true) {
```

definition and viewModel.definition are two seperate things here.
viewModel.definition is actually with the first save an empty array.
so, viewModel.definition[i] won't work ...

Comment: updated, still isn't adding the data to the selectedItems array